# Multi Column records keep last version

Tags: excel, powerquery

Hello I am trying to use Excel Power Query to do the following.
I have multiple columns
Order / Item / Version / Qty / Price

I have multiple versions of Order Items so want to keep the last version of the record
I'm thinking keep order item where version is max.

[snapshot of what I want to keep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDhwM.png)

I tried using list.max but not sure the syntax.  I played around with grouping columns and conditional column.  I think I am on the right track but just not sure how to generate the functions I need.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information about what you want to do -- show the original data, show the view you want to get to, and show what you have tried

Comment: Please share what steps you have taken to resolve and include a sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell if you want the max version of [Order & Item] or [Order] or [Item]

I am going to assume you want to only keep the highest version number of the combination of Order & Item

Load the data into powerquery.  Data .. from table/range....

Click select Order and Item columns, right click, Group By

Set up the group like below image .  Column Count / Operation Max /on Version column, and column Data /  Operation All Rows
[image]

use arrows atop the new column to expand all the columns [x] except the ones you used in the initial group; here we just need to [x] version column

[image]

Add column .. custom column ...

```
= if [Count]=[#"CHANGE_VERSION_NUMBER"] then "keep" else "remove"
```

Then use the drop down in that column to unitick and filter out [x] the remove word

[image]

Right click and remove any extra columns

file.. close and load .... your data back into excel

Comment: Won't you get the same result if you eliminate the `All Rows` aggregation from the `Group By` and delete everything from `Expanded Data` down?

Comment: I was assuming more columns were coming, unless you interpreted the original question differently

Comment: Good point. Although I'd probably just do that extraction as part of the `Table.Group` function.  Of course, he'd have to get into the Advanced Editor to do that.